# Probability of overlap of two isolated harmonically bound penetrating spheres of diameter $d$ at an average separation $a$

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, spring, crystals

Consider I have an Einstein crystal with spheres residing at simple cubic lattice points with lattice constant $a$. Each sphere has diameter $d$. Each sphere is connected with it's lattice site with harmonic spring with spring constant $k$. The temperature of the system is $T$. I want to calculate analytically, the probability of two nearest neighbor spheres to overlap as a function of T,k,a and d. How do I approach?